# Disabling ASLR causes fread() to fail in c program

Tags: c, stack

I am working on a homework assignment concerning a bufferOverflow.
The test program uses `fread()` to read 4096 bytes from a file.

When I set kernel.randomize_va_space to 0, and run the program in gdb, I can see that the fread() command returns nothing.

If I set kernel.randomize_va_space to either 1 or 2, and rerun the program using gdb, I can see the expected data in the buffer where fread stores the file.

Why would ASLR cause fread to stop working properly?

FYI: this is ubuntu 12.0.4 64-bit, and the program was compiled with the -c99 and -m32 flags to gcc.

The test program I was given for this assignment is as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define READSIZE 0x1000

void countLines(FILE* f){
  char buf[0x400];//should be big enough for anybody
  int lines=0;
  fread(buf,READSIZE,1,f);  

  for(int i=0;i<0x400;i++)
    if(buf[i] == '\n')
      lines++;


  printf("The number of lines in the file is %d\n",lines);
  return;
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){
  if(argc<2){
    printf("Proper usage is %s <filename>\n",argv[0]);
    exit(0);
  }
  FILE* myfile=fopen(argv[1],"r"); 
  countLines(myfile);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run it in gdb, I place my breakpoint on the line:

```
  for(int i=0;i<0x400;i++)
```

In gdb, I then do the following:

```
(gdb) x $esp
0xbffff280    0xbffff298
```

If I do:

```
(gdb) x /12wx $esp
```

I can see that the first 4 bytes are the address of buf, the next 4 bytes are the 0x1000 passed to fread and the next 4 bytes are 0x01 which was also passed to fread.

This looks to me like the stack frame for the fread function not the stack frame for `countLines()`.

Why wouldn't $esp be pointing to the current stack frame not hte one that was just exited?

### Update

I modified the code as follows:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define READSIZE 0x1000

void countLines(FILE* f){
  char buf[0x400];//should be big enough for anybody
  int lines=0;
int ferr=0;
  fread(buf,READSIZE,1,f);  
ferr=ferror(f);
    if (ferr)
        printf("I/O error when reading (%d)\n",ferr);
    else if (feof(f))
        printf("End of file reached successfully\n");

  for(int i=0;i<0x400;i++)
    if(buf[i] == '\n')
      lines++;

  printf("The number of lines in the file is %d\n",lines);
  return;
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){
  if(argc<2){
    printf("Proper usage is %s <filename>\n",argv[0]);
    exit(0);
  }
  FILE* myfile=fopen(argv[1],"r"); 
  countLines(myfile);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run it with ASLR diabled, I get:
I/O errorwhen readin (1)

If I run it with ASLR enabled (value=1),
 get
EOF reached.

Comment: Doesn't help that much when we can't see the surrounding code. Yet I don't see any `feof()` and `ferror()` calls - how can you know what's really happening? Did you read `fread()` documantation? (Not mentioning the magical constant `0x400`.)

Comment: Yes I have read the fread() documentation :-) The assignment is on bufferoverflows, and we were given the sourcecode.

Comment: I see... Well, the code really is crappy (too much for my taste even if I consider the intention, but maybe it will be used for other exercises as well...).

Comment: agreed Evenwith the addition o a little error checkig the code is pretty poor.

Comment: `strace` it. You'll probably getting `EFAULT` when the dest buffer falls off a mapped page.

Comment: You've explicitly coded an undefined behavior - reading 0x1000 bytes into a buffer of 0x400. Why are you expecting it to behave predictably?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev the question is why does ASLR matter for `fread()`. The behaviour is pretty much well defined - the function reads data into a buffer and does no checking on the output buffer whatsoever - actually it can't do the checks anyway.

Comment: Writing past the end of a C array is undefined behavior, even if fread() does it.

Answer (score 2):

`fread()` reads up to `nitems` elements of `size` size into an array pointed to by `ptr`. It is the programmer's responsability to ensure the array is big enough.

That last part is important. `fread()` has no way of knowing the actual size of the array. It will happily read stuff and store it past the end of the array. Accessing past the end of the array results in Undefined Behavior: there is no guarantee as to what will happen, notably, in this case, it can result in arbitrary code execution.

As to why sometimes it bombs and sometimes not:

With no ASLR you had this:

```
(gdb) x $esp
0xbffff280    0xbffff298
```

with the buffer at address `0xbffff298`. The top of the stack is at `0xbfffffff`, which leaves 3432 bytes between the start of the buffer and the end of the stack. When trying to read into the buffer, the process has nothing mapped at `0xc0000000` in userspace (which you can check with `cat /proc/<pid>/maps`, to see the process' userspace mappings) , so the underlying `read()` system call fails with `EFAULT - Bad address`.

With ASLR, there is some randomization for stack placement. The stack base has ~11 bits <sup>1</sup> of randomness on x86 ([arch/x86/include/asm/elf.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/elf.h?v=3.11#L295)):

```
/* 1GB for 64bit, 8MB for 32bit */
#define STACK_RND_MASK (test_thread_flag(TIF_IA32) ? 0x7ff : 0x3fffff)
```

and the stack top has 9 additional bits of randomness ([arch/x86/kernel/process.c:arch_align_stack()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/process.c?v=3.11#L459), called from [fs/binfmt_elf.c:create_elf_tables()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c?v=3.11#L171)):

```
if (!(current->personality & ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE) && randomize_va_space)
    sp -= get_random_int() % 8192;
return sp & ~0xf;
```

So, `arch_align_stack()` offsets the stack top [0,8176] bytes, in 16 byte increments, i.e, the initial stack pointer may be moved 0, 16, 32, ..., 8176 bytes from its original position.

So, with your 3432 bytes (the buffer, plus space for `argc`, `argv`, `envp`, `auxp`, assorted pointers to them, and padding), plus the variable ASLR offset, you have only ~8% chance of having less than 4096 bytes on your stack, which would allow you to see the SEGV with ASLR on. Just try a lot of times, and you should see it about once every 12 tries.

---

<sup>1</sup> The stack base can also be moved an additional page, see [fs/exec.c:setup_arg_pages()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/exec.c?v=3.11#L673):

```
stack_top = arch_align_stack(stack_top);
stack_top = PAGE_ALIGN(stack_top);
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the `fread()` arguments on stack, that's correct - these are stored before the caller's BP value is pushed on the stack by the callee, so they are part of the caller's stack frame - check [x86 stack frame description](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/). On x86-64 you won't see them since they are passed to the callee in registers.

As for the ASLR error, get the error description with `perror()`. Or better install debuginfo packages for glibc, so that you can trace the code into `fread()` itself.

Comment: Ok so te error message returned by perror was "bad address (value 14)". Hopefully I will have some time to install the debuginfo packages as you reccommended.

Comment: @DonRaikes: bad address is `EFAULT`. It means that you are trying to write outside a mapped area: `0xbffff298 + READSIZE` > `0xbfffffff`, which is the last byte in the mapped stack, which you can see with `cat /proc/<pid>/maps`. Turning ASLR on, you may get "lucky" and get enough stack space after your buffer to be able to overwite it without triggering a SEGV.

Comment: @ninjalj That might be an explanation, but imho a rather flaky one, if it is repeatable (or the ASLR would have severe deficiencies). However, checking the mapping once the process is running seems to be the right way to go (wherever it leads).

Comment: @peterph: It is **the** explanation, and it's not flaky. With no ASLR, there is no padding at the end of the stack, so you get 3431 bytes for your overflowed buffer. With ASLR on, you get something between (3431+ _n_ ,3431+ _m_) additional space, where _n_ and _m_ are numbers I'd have to look up, but probably enough to avert the SEGV.

Comment: Ok, (_n_, _m_), is (0, 8192) in 16-byte increments for x86, see `arch/x86/kernel/process.c:arch_align_stack()`. So it only adds 9 bits of entropy, and makes attempts at guessing addresses only 2^9=512 times harder. And you only have ~8% odds of hitting a SEGV with ASLR on.

Comment: Actually, make that [0,8192) i.e. 0 to 8176 inclusive.

Comment: Note that the stack base is also randomized (another 5 bits of entropy): http://security.stackexchange.com/a/18557

Comment: @ninjalj thanks for explaining. I didn't expect there to be that much unused but allocated space - I expected the stack to be page aligned (at the topmost virtual address (i.e. the stack bottom)). And even if not I would have expected the free space in the range [0-PAGEZISE).

Comment: Wow, this is good ino.  I did discover something interesting. This problem only happens inside of a vm.  I too my code to a laptop running debian 7 wheezy, and the fread error stoped happening.  I do geet a segmentation fault, but I am tryingto track that down now.

Answer (score -1):

I never figured out why the fread() function ws failing so I replaced it with an fgets() function and finished the assignment.

Thank you everyone for all the help.
This forum is great!